# Contacts app: What does the small colored green or orange circle above the account icons mean?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, skype, app-icons, contact-shortcut

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII when I view my contacts list in the Contacts application each contact entry has a list of small icons on the lower-right hand side corresponding to accounts where that contact is listed such as Skype, Google, WhatsApp, etc... as
shown on the following screenshot (contact pictures and names have been scribbled
out for privacy reasons, click to enlarge):

[image: Contacts app on Samsung Galaxy SIII]

Above the list of account icons, for some contacts either a green circle with a white circumference or an orange circle with two white clock hands and a white circumference appears in the upper-right hand corner of the contact entry in the list. Obviously green means available, and orange means away, but I am unable to figure out which of the three applications Google, Skype, WhatsApp, other, or whichever this dot corresponds to. First I thought that if the green dot was above the skype icon, then the contact was available on skype, but the last time I checked one of my contacts was associated with only one account,
namely skype, but when I logged into skype the contact was offline.

Can someone please help me figure out what the green or orange dots in the upper-right hand corner of contact entries in the Contact application mean?

Thanks.